# read mp3 tags from files in a directory

Tags: c#

I am using the following API
https://gist.github.com/1285901

I have this code so far but when it tries to read the tags they all return blank (by tags I mean artist info ect)

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using Microsoft.WindowsAPICodePack.Shell;
using Microsoft.WindowsAPICodePack;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Files();
            Console.Read();
        }
        public static void Files()
        {
            FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(@"C:\Users\santised\Desktop\music\");
            DirectoryInfo di = fi.Directory;
            FileSystemInfo[] fsi = di.GetFiles();
            foreach (FileSystemInfo info in fsi)
            {
                Console.Write(info.Name.Replace(".mp3", "") + " Tags: " + Tags(@"C:\Users\santised\Desktop\music\" + info.Name) + "\r\n");
            }
        }
        public static String Tags(String fileName)
        {
            if (File.Exists(fileName))
            {
                var file = new FileInfo(fileName);
                String returnval =  String.Join("; ", file.GetTags()); // .GetTags() is from the api on gist hub
                return returnval;
            }
            return "None;";
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The library you are using retrieves tags attributed to files within Windows: it does not retrieves MP3 meta data (ID3) tags. You will need to find a library that is capable of reading ID3 tags, e.g. [TagLib Sharp](http://www.novell.com/products/linuxpackages/opensuse11.1/taglib-sharp.html).

Answer (score 0):

you can use taglib-sharp

download from [here](http://download.banshee.fm/taglib-sharp/)

and then try

```
var file = TagLib.File.Create(address);
              var t1 =  file.Tag.Copyright;
              var t2 =  file.Tag.Album;
              var t3 =  file.Tag.AlbumArtists;
              var t4 =  file.Tag.Title;
              var t5 =  file.Tag.Comment ;
              var t6 =  file.Tag.Composers ;
              var t7 =  file.Tag.Conductor ;
              var t8 =  file.Tag.Grouping;
              var t9 =  file.Tag.Artists ;
```